# Need help with regex for JAX-RS path template

Tags: regex, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS service that works very well with the following path template:

```
@Path("/country/{countryIso:\\w{2}}")
```

But now I want to expand on that by changing it to

```
@Path("/country/{countryIso:.+}")
```

Which will will match any stream of characters after "`/country/`". But I can't figure out how to restrict those characters to the regex that I had previously. I want to enforce that only 2 characters are provided for each country ISO code.

Examples: 
http://localhost/myService/country/BR/MX - should be valid

http://localhost/myService/country/BR/fred - should be invalid and not allowed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to expand it. Can you elaborate a bit more on that? Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Expand it? What I am trying to accomplish it restricting the values that can be specified for country iso codes. They can only be 2 Alpha characters, so I want to restrict the input thus preventing bad data. I want to allow for multiple iso codes to be specified in the uri so the client can request multiple countries, as outlined in my example above. The request was for Brazil and Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps use:

```
@Path("/country/{countryIso:\\w{2}(/\\w{2})*}")
```

That would match BR, BR/MX, BR/MX/ad but not BR/fred.